# Jquery addClass removeClass if clicking same class

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

This code below works. I am trying to also add that if the .hero-build-wrap already added the class to hero-build , and you click it again it removes it.
I tried with .toggleclass instead of .addClass but didnt work

```
$(function() {
  $(".hero-build-wrap").click(function() {
    $(".hero-build").removeClass("hero-selected");
    $(this).children(".hero-build").addClass("hero-selected");
  });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="hero-build-wrap">
   <a class="hero-mini hero-mini-assa">
     <img class="hero-hover-big" src="">
     <img class="hero-hover-small"src=">
   </a>
   <div class="hero-build hero-selected">
      <a href="">
        <p>This is a test</p>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p>Anothertest</p>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line that adds the class

```
$(function() {
  $(".hero-build-wrap").click(function() {    
    $(this).children(".hero-build").toggleClass("hero-selected");
  });
});
```

If you add a class , then toogle that class , the end result would be it would cancel adding it

---

That being said, you may also be trying to remove the class elsewhere since `$().children` is a very strange call

If so you can do something like:

```
$(function() {
  $(".hero-build-wrap").click(function() { 
    var $children =  $(this).children(".hero-build").toggleClass("hero-selected");
    $('.hero-selected').not($children).removeClass("hero-selected");
  });
});
```

Comment: always try to provide expected behavior also along with some basic html structure... I had to assume there were other elements involved ...and happened to guess correctly

Comment: Oh yeah, I just realised that it does not work correctly, because it adds the hero-selected to another div too, and it shouldnt. It still works but I think it does more than it should. Let me add the html in a sec.

Comment: With the code it also gets added to the div with the class hero-mini

Comment: fixed...just needed the `".hero-build"` selector in `children()`